# pandas dropna drops more than isna counts

Tags: pandas, dataframe, null

I've got a 3-column dataset with 7100 rows.

`data.isna().sum()` shows, that one column contains 117 NaN vlaues, the others 0.
`data.isnull().sum()` shows also 117 for one and 0 for the other columns.

`data.dropna(inplace=True)` drops 351 rows. Can anyone explain this to me? Am I doing anything wrong?

Edit:

I now examined the deleted rows. There are 351 rows deleted, where `dropped.isna().sum().sum()` shows a total of 117 NaN values.

`dropped[~dropped['description'].isna()]` shows an empty table. So the result seems to be correct as far as I can see.

Now I'm just curious how the difference in counting occurs.

Sadly I'm not able/allowed to provide a data sample.

Comment: Ideally provide a sample of the data

Comment: but `data.isna().sum().sum()` shows an overall total of 117 NaN values. There are less total NaN values, than rows dropped

Comment: We can't debug without data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. pretty simple...
I've got three columns, one column contains 117 NaN values. 117 values for 3 columns are a total of 351 fields to be deleted. Since i used the `df.size` to measure the deleted size, which counts fields and not rows, I got 351 "deleted fields", which is totally correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

data.isna().sum() returns the total number of NAN values in your dataframe and using data.dropna() will drop all NAN values. You can specifically check the number of NAN values by creating a subset for example: nan_rows=dataframe[dataframe.columnNameWithNanValues.isna()] to check for the NAN values and then return the shape of your dataframe.
Next, use .dropna() without the inplace=True argument to drop NAN and Null values.